# Problems with utf-8 strings in Rails-app on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nokogiri, urlencode

Within my Rails-app I'm opening a URL with Nokogiri like this:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(link), nil, 'utf-8')
```

While the same code works fine on a Windows machine it fails to open the URL on a Linux machine as soon as the URL contains utf-8 characters, e.g. 'ß'.

Windows converts this **ß** to an HTML compatible **%C3%9F** and the URL can be opened without any issues. On Linux ß is converted to **ÃŸ** and the command fails.

How can I align the encodings? Is it a Ruby issue or is it a Linux issue? Where and how can I fix the problem?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding the URL may solve the issue

```
 Method: ERB::Util#url_encode
```

Comment: Hi Mukund, I used URI::encode instead but this did the trick as well. Thanks for you hint. Sometimes it's just that easy. But I'm still wondering why Windows and Linux (or the ruby interpreters on both machines) are dealing URL strings so differently while all other strings seam to be handled identically.

Comment: Thanks & glad to know it worked. Regarding your second question, I think you should check your locale setting of your Linux machine using command " locale -a". Then find whether your machine supports your language utf-8 or not.